# How to put JSON object restored from chrome.storage.local into a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm trying to build a little chrome extension, and, shortly, I have a popup where the user is prompt to flag/unflag a set of checkboxes. A function than modify a JSON object according to checked/unchecked boxes and later saves it in chrome.storage.local.

So far so good; problems starts at a later stage, when I try to recover the stored data into the content_script.
I managed to pass the object into an alert, but, in order for my script to work, I need that JSON to be stored back into a var.

This is the code I inserted in the **popup.js** and that works fine

```
chrome.storage.local.set({
        capacity: object
    }, function() {
        console.log('stored with chrome.storage.local');
      });
```

here's the code I have in the actual **script**:

```
var capacity;

load();

function load() {
chrome.storage.local.get('capacity', function(result){
        capacity = result.capacity;
        alert(result.capacity);
}
```

I'm trying to get capacity to be the same var it was on popup.js when I saved it, but after several attempts I only managed to get the values printed in the alert.

So my question is: is it possible to do this? Where am I getting this wrong?

Comment: You need to use `result.capacity` inside the callback, not elsewhere, not as a global variable.

Comment: So I guess for my purposes I'll have to use the basic locale storage and pass it via the messaging API. Quick question about this as it's not clear to me: does it mean I have to implement a background page or can I still skipe that?

Comment: AFAICT you can still use chrome.storage.local. In either case there's no need for a background page.

Comment: Hmm not sure how to do that though - if I pass it via chrome.local.storage how could I use the values besides to print them? I have a function in my script that depends on the values in the JSON to work

Comment: Seems to me that the only way to use data I get from chrome.storage is to put all my script into the callback function within the chrome.storage.local.get method - Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes. It can also be in another global function so your callback will call it after setting a global capacity.

Comment: Well I guess this question can be marked as solved - thanks to your help I got my code to work! Really, thanks a lot!